# Code is not getting Update in IOS on TestFlight build

Tags: react-native, mobile, testflight, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm uploading a codepush to the staging environment, my codepush doesn't show any errors in the terminal, but the changes don't reflect in the iOS app in testflght

Dependecies: - CodePush (from ../node_modules/react-native-code-push)

I've already checked the version of the app on testfligthy and I'm trying to make the code puhs for this version, but nothing reflects in the app